# AWS - Repository not able to download redshift jdbc jar

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, sbt

I am trying to use redshift jdbc jar . I using the Amazon repository given in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html. However the jar is AWS jar doesnt seem to download . Any pointers

Comment: Did you find any leads?

Comment: nope :( I downloaded the jar and put it into my repo. May have to raise an AWS ticket